# Shuffling an array of NSNumbers & converting back to ints

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an NSMutableArray urlArray of size n, I want to randomly choose 4 of these URLs from the total number of elements in the array.

However I don't want to shuffle urlArray directly, I'd prefer to make an "indexArray"  [0 ... (n-1)] & shuffle these, & then use the first 4 elements of the shuffled indexArray to decide which elements I choose from urlArray.

First off I created the indexArray as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStems; i++) {

    [indexArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];

}
```

This allowed me to shuffle my indexArray, so far so good. Because I used the 
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i] method, the elements in the shuffled indexArray are NSNumbers.

Is there a way to convert the NSNumber objects in indexArray into ints?

I attempted to use the intValue function but this didn't appear to be what I needed.

I also tried creating a c style array but that wasn't so successful either - I'd like to stick with objective-c syntax if possible.

Any ideas? any hints appreciated :)

Comment: Did you try `[[indexArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue]`? What results did you get that you didn't expect?

Comment: I tried intValue but the number (something like 972378, from what I remember) returned indicated an error, at which point I thought i was on the wrong track. Your suggestion did work so thank for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just create a normal c array, shuffle that and then use the first four integers in the array as the for random index?

something like

```
int* index = malloc(numberOfStems*sizeof(int));
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStems; ++i)
{
   index[i] = i;
}

for (int i = numberOfStems - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
   int randomIndex = arc4random() % i;
   int tmp = index[i];
   index[i] = index[randomIndex];   
   index[randomIndex] = tmp;
}
```

now use index to access the URL's

EDITED: updated algorithm (although not really related to OP question)

Comment: You should always use `arc4random()` in preference to `rand()` because its results are a lot more (pseudo)random.

Comment: The shuffle phase is incorrect and will produce biased results. [Doing it right](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) is not significantly more complicated, though.

Comment: This turned out to be the most elegant way to go about my solution, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

For a temporary array that stores only integers *and* gets thrown away after a relatively short task I would definitely prefer a C-style array: this would avoid a great deal of overhead, and is also simple to read.

```
int *array = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*numberOfStems);
for (int i = 0 ; i != numberOfStems ; i++) {
    array[i] = i;
}
// Do the shuffle
// Pick first four, and do whatever you need to do
// ...
// Now that you are done with the array, do not forget to free it:
free(array);
```

Comment: If the (smallish) C array is created in a function/method and not need after that function/method returns you change replace `malloc` with `alloca` and drop the `free` - `alloca`'ed objects are automatically freed when the calling function/method returns.